# get string between characters in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have output string like

`Reg. Contact : sip:2001@192.168.50.138:5089;line=6640f2cd1b461a5`

I want only IP address .string between @ and :.How can I get It?

Comment: @CollinD.got solution.

Comment: Maybe something like `@.+?:`?

Comment: If you solved this you can probably delete it; or post your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
  $input = "Reg. Contact :sip:2001@192.168.50.138:5089;line=6640f2cd1b461a5";
  preg_match('~@(.*?):~', $input, $output);
  echo $output[1]; 
?>
```

Comment: Probably want `+` instead of `*` so that something is in there. Also do you care about it being an IP or just any content?

Comment: @chris85 It can be IP or domain

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $str="Reg. Contact :sip:2001@192.168.50.138:5089;line=6640f2cd1b461a5";
    $start=strpos($str,"@");
    $end= strrpos($str,":");
    $len=$end-$start;
    echo substr($str,$start+1,$len-1);

?>
```